# Can't manage to correctly configure the hamburger and close symbols

Tags: html, css

With `right: 0;`, The menu is appearing on the right side. When I want to close it, I'm changing to `right: -200px`; so that I get the mobile page without the menu coming to the right. I want the `fa-bars` symbol to appear when the menu is not opened (`right: -200px;`), and the `fa-xmark` element when the menu is appearing (`right: 0px;`). I've tried many variations of the code and I still couldn't manage to do it.

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav_links ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  nav .fa-bars {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .nav_links {
    position: absolute;
    background: lightpink;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  nav .fa-xmark {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_links">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
    <a class="button1" href="#"><button>My Instagram</button></a>

  </ul>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't see `right: -200px` anywhere in your CSS

Comment: i will program `right: -200px` to `right:  0` with javascript code. the problem is that i can't manage to make `fa-bars` stick when the menu is not open, and to make `fa-xmark` stick when the menu is opened

Comment: if you are adding `right: -200px` to the whole `nav`, then you will surely move all of them. You need to either only move the `ul` or make some changes to your markup and apply styling accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />

    <style>
      @media (max-width: 700px) {
          
        body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        
        .nav-container {
          height: 300px;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
        }

        .nav-container i {
          float: right;
          margin: 10px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .nav-links {
          position: absolute;
          list-style: none;
          top: 30px;
          right: 0;
          width: 100px;
          padding: 20px ;
          background: pink;
          transition: 0.3s linear;
        }

        .nav-links.active {
          right: -140px;
        }

        .nav-links li {
          margin: 20px;
        }

        .nav-links li a {
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="nav-container">
      <i onclick="hanldeMenuClick()" class="fas fa-bars"></i>

      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <a class="button1" href="#"><button>My Instagram</button></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>
      const btn = document.querySelector(".fas");
      const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

      function hanldeMenuClick() {
        navLinks.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```